# Chatty comments

Tags: discussion

[*thank you* is network-wide considered fluff in questions and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).  I've been removing fluff out of questions here throughout time, however, my flag for [this comment](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/4884/models-for-online-markets-with-reputation-system/4888#4888) was rejected.

Do we feel different here about chatty comments than elsewhere?

Answer (score 4):

No, you're quite right and your flag was rejected in error.